# Run multiple websites in Apache2 with variable subdomain

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

I would like to run multiple websites, and I would like each website (differentiated by a subdomain) to point to a different DocumentRoot.

My Setup

```
Host Machine: Mac (Lion)
Development Machine Ubuntu 10.04 (a vm using VirtualBox)
```

From the Mac's browser, I want to be able to access

```
http://website1.dev
http://website2.dev
```

Appreciate any help that can be given.

Note: When I try to use a ServerName I get

```
 apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1 for ServerName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you seen or read the VirtualHost examples provided in the latest online Apache documentation? [This specific section](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html#purename) (the first one on the list) on "running several name-based web sites on a single IP address" should help you, it seems to be exactly what you are attempting to do. Here's the snippet, modified for your needs:

```
# Ensure that Apache listens on port 80
Listen 80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /www/website1
    ServerName website1.dev
    # (Other directives here)
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /www/website2
    ServerName website2.dev
    # (Other directives here)
</VirtualHost>
```

You will have to elaborate more if this does not work. What's your Apache version? What are you current httpd.conf and virtualhost.conf file contents?